# Use class attribute in method

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
simpledata = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [1,2,3,4,5], 
                           "B" : [6,7,8,9,0], 
                           "C" : ["A", "B", "A", "D", "E"], 
                           "F" : [1.3, 2.4, 3.5, 5.6, 6.7]})
class MyViz:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.simplelen = len(df)

    def simpleprint(self):
        print(self.simplelen)

MyViz.simpleprint(simpledata)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'simplelen'
```

All I need is the len of dataset in the simpleprint method.

Another attempt

```
class MyViz:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.simplelen = len(df)

    def getlen(self):
        return len(self)

    def simpleprint(self):
        print(self.getlen(self))

MyViz.simpleprint(simpledata)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'getlen'
```

Comment: Not sure if just a stack overflow formatting issue, but your methods are all indented within your class definition, right?

Comment: I am worried about the `__init__` definition as it is calling `df` as argument but trying to get the length of `dataset`, which is undefined.

It should be `len(df)`.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the edit, it was on StackOverflow only. KingDarBoja I have made the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an *instance* of `MyViz` in order to call the method `simpleprint`.

```
m = MyViz(simpledata)
m.simpleprint()
```

Currently, you are using the technique of passing an expicit argument to bind to `self` to `MyViz.simpleprint`, but you are passing an instance of `DataFrame`, not `MyViz`. The following would be legal, though unorthodox:

```
m = MyViz(simpledata)
MyViz.simpleprint(m)
```

Comment: Thanks, so foolish of me :)